# Oracle SQL: Get the First Value of each complex Group/Partition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How can I in Oracle with SQL retrieve for a table each first Column A,B, in case column B changes the value ordered by A???

Assume I have a table with date and value:

```
DATE;VALUE
01-2015;1
02-2015;1
01-2016;2
01-2016;2
01-2017:1
```

So what I want now, is **each first line once the value changes (based on certain orderning here DATE)** so from this set I want:

```
DATE;VALUE
01-2015;1 
01-2016;2 
01-2017:1
```

Now I cannot use a simply GROUP BY VALUE, because the value can flip back again (in this case to 1 in 2015 and 2017) and MIN(DATECOL) GROUP BY VALUECOL will not report this 2017.

So I was looking into Analytical functions something like:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(DATECOL),FIRST_VALUE(VALUECOL) OVER (PARTITION BY
VALUECOL ORDER BY DATECOL) FROM DATATABLE
```

But I cannot get this working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tabibtosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) makes this easy:

```
with table1 as (select to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 val from dual union all
                select to_date('01/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 val from dual union all
                select to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 val from dual union all
                select to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 2 val from dual union all
                select to_date('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 1 val from dual)
-- end of mimicking a table "table1" with data in it. See sql below:
select min(dt) dt,
       val
from   (select dt,
               val,
               dense_rank() over (order by dt)
                 - dense_rank() over (partition by val order by dt) grp
        from   table1)
group by val,
         grp;

DT                VAL
---------- ----------
01/01/2015          1
01/01/2016          2
01/01/2017          1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `LAG()` is the appropriate function, along with some other logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from datatable t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```

The only issue with your data is that the rows are not unique.  This can cause a problem, because sorting in databases is not stable (that is, two rows can be in either order).  Hopefully, in your actual data, the dates are unique or you have another id you can add to the `order by` to make the sort stable.

One brute force way of doing this is:

```
with dt as (
      select dt.*, rownum as rn
      from datatable dt
     )
select t.*
from (select dt.*, lag(value) over (order by date, rn) as prev_value
      from datatable dt
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value;
```